# Failed to Load Resource. Server Responded with a 404 on certain Products Images showing NULL!

Tags: magento2, error, product-images, 404, magento2.3.5

I found this problem on our production site. Where any Config products that have a picture assigned to the config product with out of stock options return the image null when looking at the Product Page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Images Below.

Error I am getting is **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also I noticed when I look at Application Tab in Google Chrome Dev tools there is no Image to be found.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check on the server that the file is physically there? the image path has been recorded in the database but it the file has been removed after, you will have a 404.

It's a 404 on frontend, but can you see the image in the admin panel ?

If so, try to flush the cache image from the admin.

**system > cache management**

Comment: This is kind of the answer. I had to `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize.`

Answer (score 0):

It is normal Magento 2 behavior to load the image of the associated simple product of a configurable product when a customer selects the required options.

In this case you clicked the color black, so it tried to load `pm80_black.jpg`, but it seems it doesn't exist.

You should check the black simple associated product - which image is selected as `base`, `small` and `thumbnail` in Magento admin.

Most probably the image was physically deleted from the server after it was added to the simple product, so it can't be loaded.